# Signserver exception cryptoTokenOfflineException: Signtoken isn't active

Tags: java, ejbca

I am setting up workers for PDF signing and time stamping. I use PKCS #12 certificate generated from EJBCA. key is SHA256WithECDSA encryption is ECDSA prime256v1. After using this properties(https://pastebin.com/bkpNBvc1) for setting up I am getting this results:

```
20:45:45,531 INFO  [org.signserver.server.log.IWorkerLogger] (default task-1) AllVariablesLogger; CLIENT_IP: 127.0.0.1; XFORWARDEDFOR: null; XCUSTOM1: null; LOG_TIME: 1605991545531; CLIENT_AUTHORIZED: true; EXCEPTION: org.signserver.common.CryptoTokenOfflineException: Signtoken isn't active.; WORKER_AUTHTYPE: NOAUTH; WORKER_NAME: PDFSigner; KEYALIAS: signer00003; PROCESS_SUCCESS: false; WORKER_ID: 4; CRYPTOTOKEN: CryptoTokenP12PdfSigner; REQUEST_LENGTH: 252361; REQUEST_FULLURL: http://localhost/signserver/process?null; FILENAME: document.pdf; LOG_ID: a2c32acb-f5af-4b8f-9104-0ad942c379a3; REPLY_TIME:1605991545531
```

When I use enrollment code as keystore password it provides this result.

```
22:34:59,578 INFO  [org.signserver.server.log.IWorkerLogger] (default task-14) AllVariablesLogger; CLIENT_IP: 127.0.0.1; XFORWARDEDFOR: null; XCUSTOM1: null; LOG_TIME: 1605998099578; CLIENT_AUTHORIZED: true; EXCEPTION: org.signserver.common.CryptoTokenOfflineException: No key available for purpose: signer00003; WORKER_AUTHTYPE: NOAUTH; WORKER_NAME: PDFSigner; KEYALIAS: signer00003; PROCESS_SUCCESS: false; WORKER_ID: 4; CRYPTOTOKEN: CryptoTokenP12PdfSigner; REQUEST_LENGTH: 252361; REQUEST_FULLURL: http://localhost/signserver/process?null; FILENAME: document.pdf; LOG_ID: 60961c2a-d005-4f19-a7bf-d74bb30c0448; REPLY_TIME:1605998099578
```

Any suggestions

OS version: Windows Server 2016
Java: OpenJDK 8.0.242.08 Ant: ant 1.9.14
Database: MariaDB 10.4.12
Server: Wildfly 10.1.0
Signserver Version: 5.2.0

Token is activated and and have auto-activation feature
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not enable auto-activation of the crypto token. Did you enable the crypto token and worker before sending a signing request?

Comment: I have enabled the crypto token and worker before sending a signing request also I enabled token for timestamp too. Do you think auto-activation is a problem?

Comment: Your properties file looks very strange. You have multiple properties overriding each other, like "WORKERGENID1.NAME". I think you should use one properties file for each worker. If you are unsure, start with only a single PDF worker without timestamping, so you work one step at a time.

Comment: These are multiple properties. to be exact one keystore works for  timestamp and another one works for PDF Signer. Can one keystore work for others given that certificat will have both timestamping and PDF signing designations?

Comment: As I added token is Autoactivated and active.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a crypto token in EJBCA while your log is from SignServer. These are different softwares. A crypto token in EJBCA is not used by SignServer (and vice versa), you have to activate crypto tokens in SignServer. See for example this documentation: https://doc.primekey.com/signserver520/signserver-reference/signserver-user-interfaces/administration-web/workers-page/worker-page/worker-crypto-token-page

Comment: This is what i get after doing that. It is not active because somehow certificate chain isn't available but it is available. Could you reference specific guide for this errors? https://pastebin.com/Fip2DUBZ

Comment: The error first says that your key is not available, which means you have configued to use a signing key that is not present in the P12 file that you have configured. This is on more than one signer. I would take one step back from here and start over, doing one worker at a time, following the operations guide.
https://doc.primekey.com/signserver520/signserver-operations/worker-setup

In your case you start with creating a time stamp signer, ensuring that that works. After that create the PDF signer.

Comment: Is there any reference where i can find how to make PKCS#12 Keystore with certificate for signserver with EJBCA?

Comment: It's in the SignServer documentation. There are several ways. You can just create a P12 from EJBCA, but you have to use the right aliases when configuring it in SignServer. Another way is to create a crypto token in SIgnServer, then you create a CSR from SignServer, take it to EJBCA, issue the certifiate and then import the certificate in SignServer.
For some detailed Howto, you can follow the EE howto guide. Should be usable in CE as well. https://doc.primekey.com/signserver/code-signing-how-to-guides

Comment: I created a keystore from ejbca Public Web after making all prerequisites in the admin. I used this manual https://download.primekey.se/docs/EJBCA-Enterprise/latest/Issue_a_new_PKCS_12_keystore_for_an_SSL_server.html  but got result: `- No key available for purpose: signer00002 - Certificate chain not available` The manual you linked is irrelevant as we can't access web in CE. Do you have something like that for CE?

Comment: You can use the CLI in CE. You issue is that there is no alias signer00002 in the p12 file you have downloaded. You can investigate the contents of the p12 file with for example an OpenSSL command "openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12". This will print the aliases that are in the p12 file, and then you need to use those aliases in the signer setup.

Comment: Did you try this quick start guide? https://doc.primekey.com/signserver520/signserver-operations/worker-setup/quick-start-demo-setup-using-administration-cli

Comment: Is friendly Name an alias? Yeah I tried that quick start guide and it worked okay.

Comment: yes what's called friendlyName on openssl is an alias in SignServer/Java.